# Header php Get method from list

Tags: php

In test.php I have the following code:

```
<php?
header ('Location: $link ');
$link = $_GET["id"]
 ss1 = 'http://drrd.com';
 ss2 = 'http://drrd2.com';
 ss3 = 'http://drrd3.com';
 ss4 = 'http://drrd4.com';
 ss5 = 'http://drrd5.com';
 ss6 = 'http://drrd6.com';
 ss7 = 'http://drrd7.com';
?>
```

When I go to test.php?id=ss3 the page should redirect me to http://drrd3.com/

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$links = array(
    'ss1' => 'http://drrd.com',
    'ss2' => 'http://drrd2.com',
    'ss3' => 'http://drrd3.com',
    'ss4' => 'http://drrd4.com',
    'ss5' => 'http://drrd5.com',
    'ss6' => 'http://drrd6.com',
    'ss7' => 'http://drrd7.com'
);

$id = $_GET['id'] ? ($links[$_GET['id']] ? $_GET['id']: 'ss1') : 'ss1';
header ('Location:'.$links[$id]);
ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: @PortaltvRomania added `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush` for `Cannot modify header information` error

Comment: @PortaltvRomania Could you try again?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Note it will fail if ?id on the querystring does not match an array key

```
<?php

    $locations = array(
        'ss1' => 'http://drrd.com',
        'ss2' => 'http://drrd2.com',
        'ss3' => 'http://drrd3.com',
        'ss4' => 'http://drrd4.com',
        'ss5' => 'http://drrd5.com',
        'ss6' => 'http://drrd6.com',
        'ss7' => 'http://drrd7.com'
    );

    $link = $_GET['id'];

    header ("Location: {$locations[$link]}");
```

Comment: Now what if I do `test.php?id=ss8`? Or anything else like `test.php?id=pancakes`?

Comment: @RichardA then it fails, like i noted in the description. The OP can at least do their own error checking, this should just point them in the right direction.

Comment: It will still redirect them to `null` in your code.

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: @PortaltvRomania you are outputting something else before this code or have whitespace prior to the opening <?php tag. header has to be the first thing you output or it doesn't work

Comment: @RichardA redirecting to null == fails (in my book)

Comment: its a black php page only this code is there!

Comment: @PortaltvRomania I have updated the answer to include the <?php tag and tested it, and the code works. If you copy and paste the exact code and make sure there is no whitespace before <?php it should be fine

Comment: http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/eu.php?id=ss1

Comment: @PortaltvRomania Something is being sent prior to the header function. Do you have a closing ?> tag at the bottom? If so remove it.

Answer (score 0):

when you execute `header('Location: $link')` it try to redirect you to `NULL` ,so at first you should set `$link` variable.

try this

```
$links = array(
               0=>'Fist Link',
               1=>'Second Link',
               //other links
         );

if (isset($_GET['id']) && array_key_exists($_GET['id'],$links))
    header("Location: ".$links[$_GET['id']])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
<?php
$links = Array(
 'ss1' => 'http://drrd.com',
 'ss2' => 'http://drrd2.com',
 'ss3' => 'http://drrd3.com',
 'ss4' => 'http://drrd4.com',
 'ss5' => 'http://drrd5.com',
 'ss6' => 'http://drrd6.com',
 'ss7' => 'http://drrd7.com');
if (in_array($_GET['id'], array_keys($links)))
{
  $location = 'Location: '.$links[$_GET['id']];
  header($location);
}
else
{
  // If the id is not valid, you can write an error message here.
}
?>
```

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by